# A "lax Boardman-Vogt tensor product," or what object represents duoidal categories?

Tags: higher-category-theory, operads, higher-algebra

Let me preface this by saying I'm not sure what the fundamental examples should be, and perhaps that's part of my question.

The Boardman-Vogt tensor product of $\infty$-operads $\mathcal{O}$ and $\mathcal{P}$ gives an $\infty$-operad $\mathcal{O} \otimes_{\mathsf{BV}} \mathcal{P}$ that parametrizes $\mathcal{O}$-algebras in ${\sf Alg}_\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{C})$ or equivalently $\mathcal{P}$-algebras in ${\sf Alg}_\mathcal{O}(\mathcal{C})$ in that $\mathsf{Alg}_{\mathcal{O} \otimes_\mathsf{BV} \mathcal{P}}(\mathcal{C}) \simeq \mathsf{Alg}_\mathcal{O}(\mathsf{Alg}_\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{C})) \simeq \mathsf{Alg}_\mathcal{P}(\mathsf{Alg}_\mathcal{O}(\mathcal{C}))$, and gives a closed symmetric monoidal structure on the category of $\infty$-operads.

The lax Gray tensor product gives (or is expected to give) a closed monoidal structure $-\overset{\to}{\otimes}-: \mathsf{Cat}_{(\infty,\infty)} \times \mathsf{Cat}_{(\infty,\infty)} \to \mathsf{Cat}_{(\infty,\infty)}$, where $\mathcal{C} \overset{\to}{\otimes} \mathcal{D}$ is an $(m+n)$-category if $\mathcal{C}$ (resp. $\mathcal{D}$) is an $m$-category (resp. $n$-category).

I am curious about a possible common analog of these two notions, stemming from an attempt to understand duoidal $\infty$-categories.

**Definition**: A **duoidal $\infty$-category** (after Takeshi Torii) is a monoid in the $\infty$-category $\mathsf{Mon}^\mathsf{lax}(\mathsf{Cat})$ of monoidal $\infty$-categories and *lax* monoidal functors, i.e. an $\infty$-category equipped with two laxly-commuting monoidal structures. This can be modeled explicitly as a kind of fibration over $\Delta^\mathsf{op} \times \Delta$.

More generally, Torii in https://arxiv.org/abs/2111.00158 defines $(\mathcal{O}, \mathcal{P})$-monoidal $\infty$-categories for operads $\mathcal{O}$ and $\mathcal{P}$ as $\mathcal{O}$-monoids in the cartesian monoidal category $\mathsf{Mon}^\mathsf{lax}_\mathcal{P}(\mathsf{Cat}_\infty)$.

It seems to me like there should be a single object — a kind of $\mathsf{Cat}$-enriched or "higher" $\infty$-operad — parametrizing duoidal objects in (nice enough) $(\infty, 2)$-categories, which I propose should be denoted $\mathbb{E}_1 \overset{\to}{\otimes}_\mathsf{BV} \mathbb{E}_1$ and called the "lax Boardman-Vogt tensor product." Whatever this kind of object is, and I'll call it an $(\infty,2)$-operad for the time being, it should live in a category $\mathsf{Opd}_2$ that participates in an adjunction $i: \mathsf{Opd} \leftrightarrows \mathsf{Opd}_2: (-)^\simeq$ where the left adjoint is a kind of "invert non-invertible 2-morphisms," akin to the completion functor $(-)^\simeq: \mathsf{Cat}_2 \to \mathsf{Cat}$. Under this completion functor, I'd expect an equivalence $(\mathbb{E}_1 \overset{\to}{\otimes}_\mathsf{BV} \mathbb{E}_1)^\simeq \simeq \mathbb{E}_2$. The lax BV-tensor product should also extend to a bifunctor $-\overset{\to}{\otimes}-: \mathsf{Opd} \times \mathsf{Opd} \to \mathsf{Opd_2}$. (Obviously, this need not be limited to (categorical) dimension 2; my true wish would be for a lax BV-tensor product for all "higher operads" in the way that we have a lax Gray tensor product for $(\infty,\infty)$-categories.)

**Question 1:** is there an obvious choice for what "higher operads" should be to get one that parametrizes duoidal $\infty$-categories?

**Question 2:** how might one then construct a lax Boardman-Vogt tensor product?

**Question 3:** (perhaps this should have been question 0) What are fundamental examples of higher monoidal categories?